# R: funtion which() is not found, while base package is installed

Tags: r, tidyverse

The following line in my script

```
gather(key = var, value = val,  which(names(somevar) == "somestring"):length(somevar))
```

throws an error

```
 Error in which(names(somevar) == "somestring") : 
     could not find function "which"
```

Still when I write `which` in console the output is the following...

```
> which
function (x, arr.ind = FALSE, useNames = TRUE) 
{
    wh <- .Internal(which(x))
    if (arr.ind && !is.null(d <- dim(x))) 
        arrayInd(wh, d, dimnames(x), useNames = useNames)
    else wh
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000006c6e258>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Where should I look to understand how to fix the problem?

**PS.** `base` (that contains `which` function) package is installed. `extrafont`
`tools`, `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `readxl` packages are loaded in the script. `R` version is `3.4.1` and system is `Win8`.

**UPD.** code proposed by @akrun in comments

```
somevar <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, somestring = 6:10, v3 = 11:15, v4 = 16:20);
somevar %>% gather(key = var, value = val, which(names(somevar) == "somestring"):length(somevar)) %>% head(2);
```

throws the same error...

```
Error in which(names(somevar) == "somestring") : 
  could not find function "which"
```

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example.  I tried to replicate the problem, but it is working fine for me `somevar <-  data.frame(v1 = 1:5, somestring = 6:10, v3 = 11:15, v4 = 16:20); somevar %>% gather(key = var, value = val,  which(names(somevar) == "somestring"):length(somevar)) %>% head(2); v1        var val
1  1 somestring   6
2  2 somestring   7`
`

Comment: Also   I used `R 3.4.1` on Windows 10.  Packages loaded are `extrafont_0.17, readxl_1.0.0, tidyr_0.6.3, dplyr_0.7.2`   Please check the `str(somevar)`.  I assumed it as `data.frame` If it is a `matrix`, it may not work

Comment: @akrun your code throws the same error (updated the question). `str(somevar)` returns `data.frame`

Comment: ok, can u try on a fresh session with only dplyr, tidyr, tools extrafont loaded.  BTW, what are the versions of these packages

Comment: @akrun cleared the session in `R studio` after that your code throws the same error

Comment: Ok, I tested it on R console and not on R studio.  Now, I tested on Rstudio and it is working fine for me